# MYSQL GROUP BY and WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have this query that runs just fine:

```
SELECT offers.*, COALESCE(SUM(commission),0) AS revenue, COUNT(commission) AS leads
FROM offers
LEFT JOIN offers_revenue AS or ON or.offerid=offers.offerid
GROUP BY offers.offerid
```

This returns me all of the rows in the offers table with correct comission added up.

Now I need to add a where clause (lets say, to not SUM when a certain condition is met):

```
SELECT offers.*, COALESCE(SUM(commission),0) AS revenue, COUNT(commission) AS leads, reversed
FROM offers
LEFT JOIN offers_revenue AS or ON or.offerid=offers.offerid
WHERE reversed=0
GROUP BY offers.offerid, reversed
```

First I tried just adding the WHERE clause, but that returned me an empty set of results, after digging around I've learned that you need to include where parameters in your GROUP BY and include them in the SELECT... but still, no results.

What am I doing incorrectly here? On the first query, all the results on my test tables are set to have reversed=0, so I must be missing something here.

Comment: `WHERE reversed=0`  ==> `HAVING reversed=0` Edit: add after GROUP BY.. ....

Comment: HAVING didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably `reversed` is in the `or` table.  You are turning the `left outer join` into an `inner join` by doing the comparison.  The solution is to move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT o.*, COALESCE(SUM(ofr.commission),0) AS revenue, COUNT(ofr.commission) AS leads, reversed
FROM offers o LEFT JOIN
     offers_revenue ofr
     ON `ofr`.offerid = o.offerid and ofr.reversed = 0
GROUP BY o.offerid;
```

Comment: Ah! This is preferred way to approach this I think, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try this with IF statment:

```
  SELECT offers.*, if(reversed=0 , 0 , SUM(commission)) ) AS revenue, 

        COUNT(commission) AS leads, 
        reversed                 
 FROM offers
 LEFT JOIN offers_revenue AS or ON or.offerid=offers.offerid
 GROUP BY offers.offerid, reversed
```

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax" (Yes, taking away your comment)

Comment: ahh sorry i forgot `)` ok try now

Comment: @echo_Me Small objection IF not a statement it is a function, yes `IF(a, b, c)` is a statement.

Comment: glad i helped you .:) its statment thought [look](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-statement/)